# ASP.net Membership provider client or serverside authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, membership-provider

I am developing an MVC2 application an am using the built in Membership provider. I am just asking myself if the authentication is on the server or the client?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is on the server.

*Really wanted to say* "*In the middle of nowhere*" *=)*

Answer (score -1):

As stated above, this occurs on the server as part of the Authentication/Authorization process build into Asp.net.  Override BeginRequest and AuthenticateRequest within your application class (Global.asax.cs) to compare the state of the current user (HttpContext.Current.User) before and after authentication.  For more information check out the documentation on the [HttpApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) class.

Comment: By providing such a detailed explanation you've killed all the fun of this question and answer pair =)